# Serialization of objects with collections among instance variables

Tags: java, serialization, collections

I need to write some Bus objects to a file

```
class Bus implements Serializable {
    int busno;
    int bcount;
    int availcount;
    String source,destination;
    ArrayList<Integer> booked = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer,Customer> passtick = new HashMap<>();

    Bus(int b,String src,String des)
    {
        busno = b;
        bcount = 0;
        availcount = 50;
        source = src;
        destination = des;
    }
```

A class maintains a hashset of `Bus`es

```
public class Global {
    static Set<Bus> buses = new HashSet<Bus>();
}
```

Another class has a method `exit()` which writes the `Bus`es from the hashset to a file `Buses.txt`

```
public void exit() throws Exception{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Buses.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    for(Bus b : Global.buses) {
        oos.writeObject(b);
    }
}
```

At runtime I get an exception

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Bus
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at Booking.exit(Booking.java:178)
    at ClientHandler.run(BusTicketSystem.java:172)
```

An instance of Bus class contains an ArrayList and a HashMap. Are these causing a problem in serialization? Thank you.

Comment: Nope, should be fine.

Comment: What is `Customer`? Is it declared with `implements Serializable`?

Comment: Do you have a problem or are you just asking to make sure? If you have a problem, then you need to add the error or the problem output and explain what the problem is. Making sure is easy - you run it with different inputs and see if it works.

Comment: @Quang Nguyen Yes Customer implements serializable

Comment: @RealSkeptic I get a runtime exception as mentioned in the question

Comment: Add the whole stack trace, please - including any "caused by" lines, if there are any. Make sure your project doesn't use old versions of the Bus class, or any other class named "Bus".

Comment: @RealSkeptic added stack trace.

Comment: OK, at this stage, it doesn't make sense. Either you have an old class file from an old project somewhere, or some other "Bus" somewhere. Please create a [mcve] so that we'll be able to test this for ourselves.